# How can I unlock file in c

Tags: c, system-calls, fcntl

I tried to lock-unlock file in c. If the file is exist then there is no problem but if file does not exist and file is created, file stays locked. If I tried to open the file, It did not open. It says "there is no permission to open".
Let's say file is: hey.txt, If it is exist there is no problem I can open this. But if hey.txt is not exist, file will created and write is done succesfully but I cannot open the file. I can only see file content when I wrote this sudo cat hey.txt to terminal

```
  #define WRITE_FLAGS (O_WRONLY  | O_CREAT | O_APPEND) //Write flag
        int main(int argc , char* argv[]){
       
    
        struct flock lock;
        int fd=open(argv[0],WRITE_FLAGS);
         int result_of_fcntl=0;
        if(fd==-1){
                perror("The file cannot opened.\n");
                return-1;
            }
        
            memset(&lock,0,sizeof(lock));
            lock.l_type=F_WRLCK;  
            result_of_fcntl=fcntl(fd,F_SETLKW,&lock);
        char buffer2[]={"deneme\n"};
        
                         
            int byteswritten = write(fd,buffer2,7);
            if(byteswritten==-1){
                perror("Error while writing to file:");
                return -1;
            }
        //unlock
            lock.l_type=F_UNLCK;
            result_of_fcntl=fcntl(fd,F_SETLKW,&lock);
            if(result_of_fcntl==-1){
                perror("Error:");
                return -1;
            }
            int closeFlag= close(fd);
            if(closeFlag==-1){
                perror("The file cannot closed.\n");
                return-1;
            }
         return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are providing a poorly formatted snippet.  [mre] would be much more helpful.

Comment: what is the OS and who is the directory owner where file is created.

Comment: I am using ubuntu. I create the file so I guess me is the directory owner. @Gerhard

Comment: use `ls -la` and look.

Comment: `argv[0]` is the name of the program. You probably want to open `argv[1]` instead (after checking that `argc > 1`).

Comment: @Gerhard  I look and  I am the directory owner.

Comment: @IanAbbott there is no problem with argv[0] because I use execve function.

Comment: The `struct flock lock` variable has only been partially initialized; the `l_whence`, `l_start` and `l_len` members have not been set.

Comment: Best not to abuse argv[0] like that even if you are using execve().

Comment: Returning -1 from main() will probably set the exit status to 255. Better to return a non-negative value from main().

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not file *locking*, but improperly set file permission bits at reation time. Change your call to `open` like this:

```
open(filename, O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);
```